# Why is pip asking me to choose a program to run pip?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OndVJ.png) if I do `pip install pyautogui`, or any other command with `pip`. What is happening?
**Python version:** 3.9.6
**pip version:** 21.1.3

Comment: Is cmd/shell/powershell one of the suggestions? Try letting pip run with this "program".

Comment: Type `where pip`. What are the results?

Comment: @waykiki it works with that, wonder what happened there...

Comment: That's because windows only executes a file as a program with some extensions like exe, bat, com. When you run inside cmd it wokrs because cmd is intended to execute programs independent of the extension (more like unix)

Comment: @オパラ It just happened that windows didn't know "how/where" to execute pip commands. When you run pip commands, they need to be executed from within the shell. You just needed to instruct windows how to interpret the command. Is it fully functioning now?

Comment: Yeah, its functioning now.